# Prevent digest of parent scopes in Angular

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

I am investigating Angular as a potential framework to use for an upcoming project. The test app I am making consists of an unordered list of which list items can be added to via an add link. Each list item contains a number of checkboxes. The number of checkboxes for a particular list item can be increased or decreased with plus and minus links next to each list item. Observe:

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense. Each checkbox has an `ng-model` directive binding the value of the checkbox to a property in an object. When the application is in the state above clicking any of the checkboxes fires six checks (one for each checkbox) -- the entire `$scope` of the root controller is checked for changes. Ideally, only the `$scope` of the relevant list item would be checked for changes. How can I accomplish this? I've attached my test code for reference. I've tried adding `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` to the `input` node as well as to the `li` node but this appears to increase (double) the number of checks in the digest.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="App">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-controller="LineController">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="box in line.boxes" ng-model="box.on" />
      <a ng-show="line.boxes.length > 1" ng-click="removeBox()">-</a>
      <a ng-click="addBox()">+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a ng-click="addLine()">Add</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function App($scope) {
  $scope.lines = [];
  $scope.addLine = function () {
    $scope.lines.push({
      boxes: []
    });
  };
}

function LineController($scope) {
  $scope.addBox = function () {
    var box = {};
    Object.defineProperty(box, 'on', {
      enmerable: true,
      get: function () {
        console.log('Get!');
        return this._on;
      },
      set: function (on) {
        this._on = on;
      }
    });
    $scope.line.boxes.push(box);
  };

  $scope.removeBox = function () {
    $scope.line.boxes.pop();
  };
}
```

Comment: `When the application is in the state above clicking any of the checkboxes fires six checks (one for each checkbox) -- the entire $scope of the root controller is checked for changes. Ideally, only the $scope of the relevant list item would be checked for changes` Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is that AnguarJS dirty checking is going to be too slow for your needs, your question really need to be "is AngularJS going to be to slow to build X?" If X is a 3D game with lots of constant rendering then the answer is probably yes, AngularJS is not what you want. If X is "a scalable business/consumer oriented single page application", then the dirty checking algorithm is not going to be your bottle neck.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933) has a good explanation of how data binding works and talks a bit about performance concerns.

Answer (score 1):

What about to use `$watch`. We can invoke watch only for specific row. That means if you have 4x4 matrix (4 rows , 4 columns) on any checkbox state change we call watch 4 times

```
var webApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

webApp.controller('App', function ($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [];

    $scope.addLine = function () {

        console.log("addLine");

        $scope.lines.push({
            boxes: []
        });

    };
});

webApp.controller('LineController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.addBox = function () {
        var box = {};
       /* Object.defineProperty(box, 'on', {
            enmerable: true,
            get: function () {
                console.log('Get!');
                return this._on;
            },
            set: function (on) {
                this._on = on;
            }
        });*/
        $scope.line.boxes.push(box);



        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $scope.line.boxes;
        },
        function (newValue, oldValue) {

            if(newValue == oldValue) return;
             console.log('Get new checkbox!');

        }, true);

    };

    $scope.removeBox = function () {
        $scope.line.boxes.pop();
    };
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/724/)</kbd>